# What is the meaning of this syntax in the method declaration

Tags: c++, syntax

I encountered this method and I'm not sure how to interpret it:

```
const char(*get_foo(int par))[38]
{
    return foo;
}
```

<sup>the `par` parameter is not used in the function...</sup>

And `foo` is defined as:

```
static const char bar[] = " 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
static const char(*foo)[38] = &bar;
```

`get_foo`, `foo`, and `bar` are all members of the same class.

Also, when `get_foo` is called, its return value is stored in a `const ushort*` value:

```
const ushort* baz = *instant->get_foo(some_value);
```

I didn't see that syntax before and can't understand this method declaration, what are the different parts that make up this declaration and explain how to read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function that takes an `int` and returns a pointer-to-array containing 38 `const char` types. It's not clear why the `par` parameter is not used, that would be a question for the original author.

A function like this should be read:

```cpp
const char(*get_foo(int par))[38]
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (1)
^~~~~~~~~~~~                ^~~~~ (2)
```

1. The name of the function is `get_foo`, with function parameter `int` named `par`
2. The return type is `const char(*)[38]` -- which is a pointer to an array of `char char` containing `38` entries

Due to operator precedence in C++, it leads to types that look obfuscated like this, since otherwise it would introduce syntactic ambiguities. It would be easier to read had the author of the code simply used an alias:

```cpp
using array_type = const char(*)[38];

array_type get_foo(int par);
```

which is equivalent to `const char(*get_foo(int par))[38]`